Avago MegaRaid SAS 9364-8i Foreign view
All,
My Lenovo workstation (RAID 5 & 4 disks) keeps rebooting and does not pop up the log in the Linux window. After logging into the MegaRAID, I found that the RAID configuration is missing (see image below); yet, a Foreign view lists the old RAID configuration, but there is no clear way to restore it (see pictures below).
Any ideas
Thanks
P.S. I have posted this question to another forum, but I have not yet received a clear answer.



Import it.
It's "foreign" when there is RAID metadata on disks, but there is no corresponding RAID configuration present in controller's NVRAM. The controller doesn't recognize disks as it's own, and calls them "foreign". This happens when disks with an array were re-seated to a new (blank) controller, or when disks that had contained an array were re-used, or something's wrong with the controller as it seems to be lost its NVRAM contents.
Anyway, the import foreign configuration action is supposed to read the metadata from disks and add it into controller's configuration, adopting the array which already exists. You may wish to explore the topic further. This notice by Huawei seems to look very relevant too.
If you're in doubt (rightfully so! I'd be hesitated too), do a backup first: find a HBA and dump each disks's image. That way, you're guaranteed at least to not lose the data (as you'll be given essentially infinite number of attempts to restore disks back from these images if something goes wrong). Yes, I know that'll need an awful lot of space and some time, but it's admins life.
Also, investigate further what happened with NVRAM. Check controllers logs, at least.

I cannot recover the “foreign” metadata because that option is disabled, as seen in the second figure above. Do you have any other ideas?

Maybe, it's the TUI tool you're using is deficient to not have this option, which is why it's disabled. Try booting Linux with the current state of RAID controller and use megacli tool, available at Broadcom site along with its manual. It's the software to control the card from the OS, and it can do everything from configuring the card to upgrading its firmware. For us to help you further, you have to do this, because it also can extract event logs from the card into a text file, which you have to attach to your question.

Also, you can switch the controller into HBA mode (some of firmwares have this option disabled; then you have to find another one) and try booting Linux from removable rescue media. Linux itself understands the on-disk format MegaRAID uses (it's called SNIA DDF), and is able to assemble the array. If that doesn't help, where are your backups? There are data recovery services, that offer recovery from damaged RAID metadata. It's not that hard to do, by the way; search ServerFault, I described the general procedure a few times, but you'll need a vast amount of scratch space (to hold images).

I tried booting using system rescue (https://www.system-rescue.org) yet with no success, it could not see the harddisks.

You were supposed to run megacli from it. E.g. megacli -h shows reminder, I expect to see meagcli -AdpAllInfo -a0 and megacli -PdList -a0 at least.  Then, logs. Unfortunately, I don't have megaraid at hand at the moment, and I don't remember exactly how to extract logs, so I encourage you to read megacli manual yourself.
